# Simple Calculation in Flat Cohomology

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-groups, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

**Question**: Let $R$ be a PID and let $n \geq 2$ be even. What is $H^0_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R,\operatorname{SL}_n/\mu_2)$?

**Attempt at an Answer**: From the short exact sequence of algebraic groups $1 \to \mu_2 \to\operatorname{SL}_n\to\operatorname{SL}_n/\mu_2 \to 1$, we obtain a long exact sequence in fppf cohomology given by
$$1 \longrightarrow H^0_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R, \mu_2) = \{\pm 1\} \longrightarrow H^0_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R, \operatorname{SL}_n) = \operatorname{SL}_n(R) \longrightarrow H^0_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R,\operatorname{SL}_n/\mu_2) \longrightarrow H^1_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R,\mu_2) = R^\times/R^{\times 2} \longrightarrow H^1_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R,\operatorname{SL}_n) = 1.$$

Let $K$ be the fraction field of $R$. From the above, I would guess that $H^0_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R,\operatorname{SL}_n/\mu_2)$ may be described as the subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\overline{K})/\{\pm 1\}$ consisting of matrices $M$ whose entries are units in a quadratic extension of $K$ such that the Galois-conjugate of $M$ is given by $-M$. However, I do not know how to prove this. I guess I could try to show that this description is the sheafification of $\operatorname{SL}_n(R)/\{\pm 1\}$, but that seems to require guessing the answer first, which is unsatisfying.

I do know how to answer this question when $R$ is replaced by $K$ and fppf cohomology is replaced by Galois cohomology, but I'm not sure how to imitate that argument over $R$.

**Edit**: I had previously asked this question with $\mathbb{G}_m$ replacing $\operatorname{SL}_n$; as Mindlack pointed out in the comments, the group $H^0_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R,\mathbb{G}_m / \mu_2)$ can be easily computed using the Kummer sequence.

Comment: Isn’t $H^1_{fppf}(R,\mathbb{G}_m)=H^1_{Zar}(R,\mathbb{G}_m)=\mathrm{Pic}(R)$?

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, but $\operatorname{Pic}(R) = 1$ because $R$ is a PID.

Comment: Right, of course, thank you. But isn’t $\mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m/\mu_2$ an isomorphism though, through the morphism of exact sequences $1 \rightarrow \mu_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow 1$ (where the second map is multiplication by two in the group sheaf) to $1 \rightarrow \mu_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m/\mu_2 \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: @Mindlack Oh I forgot about the Kummer sequence! That does seem to imply that $\mathbb{G}_m \simeq \mathbb{G}_m/\mu_2$. So $H^0_{\operatorname{fppf}}(R,\mathbb{G}_m/\mu_2) = R^\times$, I guess, and the above long exact sequence in cohomology is the Kummer sequence on $R$-points. I'm also interested in what happens when $\mathbb{G}_m$ is replaced by $\operatorname{SL}_n$ for any $n$, not just $n = 1$; I doubt such a simple argument would suffice in that case.

Comment: Here is an answer for $n = 2$. Then $SL_2/\mu_2 \cong GL_2/\mathbb G_m$ and the corresponding exact sequence gives $H^0(R,SL_2/\mu_2) = GL_2(R)/R^\times$. (This does fit into your sequence above.) But for general $n$, I am not quite sure. The simplest $z$-extension of $G := SL_n/\mu_2$ is $H := (SL_n \times \mathbb G_m)/\mu_2$, where $\mu_2$ is embedded diagonally, and $ker(H \to G) \cong \mathbb G_m$ (but this only gives another exact sequence, not a clean answer).

Comment: Incidentally, for $n = 4$ the group in question is $SO_6$, so the answer is $SO_6(R)$ in this case.